# Visualforce Error:javax.faces.FacesException: core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesDeveloperException

Tags: visualforce

Can any help me out with the Error in visual force page :

Error as :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesDeveloperException: Map key BXRC-25E4000-F-04 not found in map
```

In a table i would like to display the data for the previous and current year.

This is the Table (expected output):

```
 ProductName         Year       Q1       Q2   Q3    Q4       Total
 BXRC-25e4000-F-04  2014       100     200   300   400       1000 
                    2015       100                            100  
 BXRC-25e4000-F-23  2014       200                 200        400
                    2015       300                            300
 Subtotal ------------         700     200   300   600       1800
```

But i get the o/p as:

```
ProductName         Year       Q1       Q2   Q3    Q4       Total
 BXRC-25e4000-F-04  2014       500     200   300   400       1400 

 BXRC-25e4000-F-23  2014       200                 200        400

Subtotal ------------          700     200   300   600       1800
```

When i use the condition

```
if ((monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar')&&(year==previousyear))
```

i get the previous year data .

But when i use the condition for the current year ,it does not works ,throws an error.

```
if ((monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar')&&(year==previousyear ||year==currentyear))
```

or

```
if ((monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar')&&(year==currentyear))
```

Code :

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {
    public Map < String, Decimal > PartMap {get;set;}
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter4 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount4 {get;set;}  
    public Competitor__c com {get;set;}  
    public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist {get;set;}  
    public Id qId {get;set;}  
    Public string all {get;set;}  
    public integer previousyear{get;set;}
    public integer currentyear{get;set;}


    Public QuoteContentController() {}
    Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        qId = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        previousyear = date.today().year()-1;
        currentyear = date.today().year();
    }

   Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{
        disp_list = new list < wrapperclass > ();
        //Query all the list     
        List < Quote > q = [select id, Name, QuoteNumber, Effective_Date__c, Comments__c, Quote.Opportunity.id,
                                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability, Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c, 
                                    Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c, Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c, Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                                    from Quote where id = : apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
        Opportunity opp = [select id, Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), 
                                probability, AccSegment__c 
                                from Opportunity where opportunity.Id = : q[0].opportunity.id LIMIT 1];
        List < gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c > opflist = [ Select id, Name, gmod__opportunity__r.id, gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Price__c,
                                                            gmod__Month__c, gmod__date__c, gmod__Quarter__c, gmod__Amount__c, Actual_Price__c, 
                                                            gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month_Text__c, Forecast_Date__c, gmod__Product__r.Name, 
                                                            gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c 
                                                            WHERE gmod__Product__c != null and gmod__opportunity__r.id = : opp.id 
                                                            Order BY  gmod__Product__r.Name,gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc];
        //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        PartMap = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();

        for (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast: opflist) {

            String prodName = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;
            String monthText = oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;
            Integer year = Integer.valueof(oppforecast.gmod__Year__c);
            Integer previousyear = date.today().year()-1;
            Integer currentyear = date.today().year();


            Map<String, Decimal> quarterMap;
            Map<String, Decimal> amountMap;

            if ((monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar')&&(year==previousyear  )){
                quarterMap = Quarter1;
                amountMap = Amount1;
            if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

        }

       }     
            if ((monthText == 'Apr' || monthText == 'May' || monthText == 'June')&&(year==previousyear  )){
                quarterMap = Quarter2;
                amountMap = Amount2;
                if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                }
                }
            if ((monthText == 'Jul' || monthText == 'Aug' || monthText == 'Sept')&&(year==previousyear)){
                quarterMap = Quarter3;
                amountMap = Amount3;
                if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }
            }
            if ((monthText == 'Oct' || monthText == 'Nov' || monthText == 'Dec')&&(year==previousyear)) {
                quarterMap = Quarter4;
                amountMap = Amount4;
                 if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);


            wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
            w.gmod_Product = prodName;
            w.gmod_Quantity = oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;
            w.gmod_Price = oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;
            w.Name = oppforecast.Name;
            w.gmod_Quarter = oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;
            w.gmod_Month = oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;
            w.gmod_Amount = oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;
            w.Actual_Price = oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;
            w.gmod_Year = oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;
            w.gmod_date = oppforecast.gmod__date__c;
            w.gmod_Month_Text = monthText;
            w.Forecast_Date = oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;
            disp_list.add(w);
}

}            

            for (Quote qt: q) {
            System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());
                for (integer i = 0; i < opflist.size(); i++) {


                    //Instantiating the wrapper SObject     
                  /* wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database.     
                    w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Quantity = opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Price = opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;
                    w.Name = opflist[i].Name;
                    w.gmod_Quarter = opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;
                    w.gmod_Month = opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;
                    w.Actual_Price = opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;
                    w.gmod_Year = opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;
                    w.gmod_date = opflist[i].gmod__date__c;
                    w.gmod_Month_Text = opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;
                    w.Forecast_Date = opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;*/

                }//End of For loop int
            }//End of For loop Quote
        }//End of For loop gmod

  }//End of disp


    //Declare a wrapper class      
       public class Wrapperclass  {
        //custom wrapper datatype      
        Public string Name{get;set;}  
        Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
        Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
        Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
        Public string Probability{get;set;}  
        Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
        Public string External_Comment{get;set;}      
        Public string Segment{get;set;}  
        Public string Application{get;set;}  
        Public string Persona{get;set;}  
        Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}      
        Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Total{get;set;}      
        Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
        Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
        Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
        Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
        Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
        Public string Other_information{get;set;}      
        Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
        Public string Volume{get;set;} 
        Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;}     
        Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
        Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
        Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
        Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}
    }
  } //End of Class
```

VF CODE :

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" 
        applyHtmlTag="false"    showheader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="QuoteContentController" renderAs="pdf">


  <div class="title"> <center> <h2>RFQ Information  </h2> </center> </div>
  <!-- <b>General Information  </b> -->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" >
        <tr>

            <th bgcolor="Silver">General</th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Information:</th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Justification and Account </th>
            <th bgcolor="Silver">Information:</th>

         </tr>
       <!-- </table>
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">-->
       <!-- <tr width="10%">
        <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
        <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
            <td class="labelCol" >QuoteNumber:</td>
            <td class="data2Col"><apex:outputText value="{!Quote.QuoteNumber}"/></td>
             </f>
        </td>-->
            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">QuoteNumber:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quote.QuoteNumber}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">RFQ Justification:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Name}"/></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">CustomerName: </f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Name}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Main Customers of Account:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Main_Customers_of_Account__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Account Type:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Recordtype.Name}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Bridgelux Competition at Account:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Date:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Effective_Date__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Geographic regions serviced:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Servicing_Region__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Expected Order Date:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Effective_Date__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual lighting revenue:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_LED_Revenue__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Internal Comments:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Description}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual LED revenue or percent:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_LED_Revenue__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">External Comments: </f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Comments__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Annual Purchases of LED Sources (SAM):</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Probability(%):</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Probability}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Percent of LED purchases that are COB:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Segment:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c}"/></td>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Other Info:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Account.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Application:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Persona:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Geography:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.Region__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

           <!-- <tr>
            <td ><f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">Opportunity RecordType:</f></td>
            <td class="header-data"><apex:outputField value="{!Quote.Opportunity.RecordType.Name}"/></td>
            </tr> -->

          </table>


   <h3>QuotelineItems Details</h3>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead> 
                <tr>
                <!--<td bgcolor="Silver" class="header-table-heading">Part</td>-->
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">EndCustomerPrice</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Total</td>
            </tr>
          </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.QuotelineItems}" var="qli">

            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data" ><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Product2.Name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" ><apex:outputText value="{!qli.Unitprice}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.End_Customer_Price__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!qli.TotalPrice}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 




     <h3>Competitive Data</h3>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Company</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Product Series</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Part Numbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">volume</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Date Price is Valid</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.Competitor_s__r}" var="com">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!com.Name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!com.Product_Series__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Part_Number__c }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Price_Offered__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Volume__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!com.Date_Price_is_Valid__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table> 

<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total1"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total2"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total3"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total4"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total5"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total6"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total7"/>
<apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total8"/>

<h3>OpportunityForecast Details</h3>

<table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="3"  ></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="6" >FORECAST DATE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>              
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Opportunity Name</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Year</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q1 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q2 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q3 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Q4 2014 </td>

                <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Grand<br/>Total </td> 
              </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>

                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Opportunity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Year }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>

                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]+Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]+Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>

                 <!--<apex:variable var="total1" value="{!total + previousyear[opf.gmod_Year]}" />-->

                <apex:variable var="total1" value="{!total1 + Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]}" />
                <apex:variable var="total5" value="{!total5 + Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]}" />

                <apex:variable var="total2" value="{!total2 + Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]}" />
                <apex:variable var="total6" value="{!total6 + Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]}" />

                <apex:variable var="total3" value="{!total3 + Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]}" />
                <apex:variable var="total7" value="{!total7 + Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]}" />

                <apex:variable var="total4" value="{!total4 + Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}" />
                <apex:variable var="total8" value="{!total8 + Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}" />
             </tr>
           </apex:repeat> 
       </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                   <tr class="foot">
                         <tr>

                     <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data" >SubTotal :</td>
                     <td colspan="0"  class="header-table-data"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>

                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!total1}<br/>${!total5},<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!total2}<br/>${!total6},<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!total3}<br/>${!total7},<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!total4}<br/>${!total8},<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data">{!total1+total2+total3+total4}<br/>${!total5+total6+total7+total8},<br/></td>

                      </tr>    

                      <tr>

                       <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left"  align="right" class="header-table-heading">GrandTotal</td>
                       <td colspan="0"  class="header-table-heading">Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                       <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading">{!total1}<br/>${!total5},<br/></td>
                       <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading">{!total2}<br/>${!total6},<br/></td>
                       <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading">{!total3}<br/>${!total7},<br/></td>
                       <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading">{!total4}<br/>${!total8},<br/></td>
                       <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-heading">{!total1+total2+total3+total4}<br/>${!total5+total6+total7+total8},<br/></td>

                       </tr> 
                       </tr>
               </tfoot> 
             </table> 
</apex:page>
```

[image]
 Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure there is data for 2015? If you use a access a map in visualforce, the key has to be there or else you get this kind of error, it wont fail gracefully.

Comment: @CyberJus:I do have the data for 2015 , in quarter1 for the month of march I do have the data given.

Comment: @CyberJus:I have updated the code.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please add your VF code as well.

Comment: @ CyberJus:I have update the VF code.

Comment: Are you just adding another block to the VF page for 2015? Your code does not show how you are accounting for the year. If you try to get Qtr2 for 2015 it is going to throw this error because of how you are building your map since the data/key value wont be there. Structuring your code like this is going to be pretty hard to maintain later.

Comment: @CyberJus:As per the requirement the data for 2015 should get displayed in the same block .IS that im making any blunt mistakes in the code.Do we have an option to show  the data for the current year .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: So even though it says 2014, it should also include data from 2015? Why don't you just add the year filter to the SOQL query? The way you are doing it now pulls everything, you should only be pulling the data you want.

Comment: @ CyberJus:In the table when I use the year as( previous || current ) it adds the data of 2015 in 2014.I would  like the to see the data of 2014 nd 2015 sepeartely in the same table .OR If I need the 2015 data ,it doesnot display.

Comment: You just said "data for 2015 should get displayed in the same block" when I asked you how you were aggregating the data from 2015. The error you are getting then is because there is no data from Q2-4 in 2015, that is why there is no key value for those quarters. You would have to prime the keys you want to report out with 0s first. Regardless, you should still limit your SOQL query.

Comment: @CyberJus:[Select id, , gmod__Year__c,   from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Year__c=2015]   i tried this query in Developer console it gave the related record o/p for 2015,but when i tried in VF page it did not give any o/p in the table of OFD .So you mean to say if all the quarters have data than only it will get displayed in the table.

Comment: The way your code is written, yes.  If you take your maps and populate them with 0s first for all of the key values (2015 Q2-4) you want to access from Visualforce it should work better.

Comment: @CyberJus:How to take the maps and populate with zeros.Any example plz.

Comment: Map<Id, Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>> valueMap = new Map<Id, Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>>();
  for (Id productId : allYourProductIds) {
   Map<String, Decimal> quarterMap = new Map<String, Decimal> { 'Q1' => 0.0, 'Q2' => 0.0, 'Q3' => 0.0, 'Q4' => 0.0 };
   Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>> yearMap = new Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>> { previousYear => quarterMap.clone(), currentYear => quarterMap.clone()};
   valueMap.put(productId, yearMap);
  }

Comment: @ CyberJus:This nested map should be declared separetely or it should be replaced in the place of maps declared for all the quarter etc.Can u let me know where the code needs to be added plz.

Comment: It is a replacement for the separate maps you have. You could use the maps you have now, it would just take more code lines to initialize them than i have in the comment section. The concept is the same.

Comment: @CyberJus:I added the code after the line  public integer currentyear{get;set;},but the I get an Error as :expecting right curly bracket, found 'for' at the line  for (Id productId : allYourProductIds) {.

Comment: This should have another '>': 
Map<Id, Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>>> valueMap = new Map<Id, Map<Integer, Map<String, Decimal>>>();

Comment: @CyberJus:I have added the brace  while ececuting,but it throws the error at for loop line :for (Id productId : allYourProductIds) {

Comment: You have to put a list of the Ids you want to check for. What I posted was just an example, not the literal code to use.

Comment: @ CyberJus:I tried making the changes in FOR loop as[ for (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c productId : opflist)] but the system throws an Error as : Incompatible key type gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c for Map<Id,Map<Integer,Map<String,Decimal>>> at line valueMap.put(productId, yearMap); Can u plz help me out related to the code.I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: Looking at your code you probably want to change the parent Map key to String and use (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist) and then use oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name.  Did you write this code yourself or are you modifying after someone else?

Comment: @ CyberJus:Im Modifying the code.I didnt get your point.When i try for FOR LOOP [for (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast1 :oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name)],it throws an error as {Loop must iterate over a collection type of string.

Comment: That is not what I said. For loops need to iterate over collections, your opflist is a collection of gmod_Opportunity_Forecast__c objects, so it should be (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist) Then you need to do something with each of those objects in the list. Since were using a key of oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name before, that is what I suggested. That means Map<Id, Map.... wont work, it would need to be Map<String, Map... then

Comment: @CyberJus:Im still confused.Where should i use these Maps and For loop is it after the FOR LOOP of gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist) and the wrapper class or before.Plz can u precisely let me know.I shall appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your class

```
    Quarter1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
    Quarter2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
    Quarter3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
    Quarter4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
```

**Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4 maps are always new( empty) maps**. You are not adding any key/value into the map but in your visual force page you are trying to get the value for all the maps using the key (**prodname**) by

```
              <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount1[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount2[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount3[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Quarter4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/>$<apex:outputText value="{!Amount4[opf.gmod_Product]}"/>,<br/></td>
```

**To simplify**

The quarter maps look like this

```
String(key)      Decimal(Value)

(empty)          (empty)
```

You are instructing your vf page to go and fect a key (BXRC-25E4000-F-04) for which the controller says "Key not found in the map"

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.Apart from map do we have any alternate to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

should the "E" be lower case.  BXRC-25**E**4000-F-04.

or

you are trying the leave the product name blank for presentation purposes but you are also using the product name as the key in your map. Add the product name as a field in the map values for presentation and do not blank the map key.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I have updated the complete code.Any help very much appreciated.